# how to send data from angularjs to server distant using ngresouce

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how to use ngResource module

1. to send data to server.
2. and get data from server
3. i trying to send data to solr server
4. using angularjs api
5. and npm package manager to install package to my application
6. thank you  for your help

controller.js:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('Mycontroller',function($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.requete = $resource('http://localhost:8983/solr/#/cv/:action',
        {action:'cv.json', q:'angularjs', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},
        {get:{method:'JSONP'}});

    $scope.chercher = function () {
        $scope.repnses = $scope.requete.get({q:$scope.formInfo.Quoi});
    };
})
```

search.html :client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body >
      <div ui-view></div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Formation</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="app/index.html">Formateur</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="app/search.html" active>Client</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div ng-contoller="Mycontroller">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="table">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label for="inputQuoi" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quoi</label>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <input class="form-control" id="inputQuoi" placeholder="quoi" ng-model="formInfo.Quoi" required>
          </td>
      <td><button type="submit" ng-click="chercher()" class="btn btn-primary" >chercher</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</form>
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="repnse in reponses.results">
            <td>{{requete.text}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    <script src="app/js/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem.
But you have this...

```
<tr ng-repeat="repnse in reponses.results">
        <td>{{requete.text}}</td>
</tr>
```

But dont really have any variable called reponses.results, or anything with requete as the variable.

Your code puts the get response in $scope.repnses
So to loop through that you need to refer to it properly.

```
<tr ng-repeat="repnse in repnses.results">
      // Then refer to the variables inside of it using the repnse variable.
      // not requet, dont even know where you're getting that from
        <td>{{repnse.text}}</td>
</tr>
```